# How to test functions that use sink(type = "message") with testthat

Tags: r, testthat, sink

Within an R package I wrote a function that redirects all output from a sourced script to a log file using

```r
sink(file = "some.log", type = "output")
sink(file = "some.log", type = "message")
source("script.R")
```

within the function. Now I want to test if this function works as expected which means that I need to test if certain output *(including messages)* was written to the specified log file.

This works fine when I run the test script in the console. But when I use `devtools::test()` or R CMD check, the messages are captured somewhere else and don't appear in the log file.

I understand that this behavior is somehow necessary for testthat to work, but how can I test if my function call produced all expected messages?

Comment: An R package should not use `source`.

Comment: But I need a function which sources a script file (the path of the script file is not hardcoded, of course!) and logs all input and output. What would be the "correct" / best practice solution to this if I should not use `source`?

Comment: if you are creating a package, then you can call other functions within your package without the need of source.

Comment: @Moh, I know. But I need a function so that users of my package can easily source their scripts and log everything which happend in there.

Comment: Is this some kind of utility package to support users who use `source`?

Comment: @Roland: Yes, that's one thing the package does. It also provides functions which the users should use in their scripts (which they then `source`) and print specific messages to the log file.

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach but good luck.

Comment: I'm open to better approaches if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is to leave it up to end-users to call `sink()` rather than include it as a function in your package. You can provide examples in a vignette to show users how you intend them to use `sink()` with their scripts.

Edit: you might find this vignette on test fixtures helpful, especially the case study on `usethis`: https://testthat.r-lib.org/articles/test-fixtures.html#case-study-usethis